# Spring FileNotFoundException

Tags: spring, filenotfoundexception

I wrote below 2 Java classes for learning Spring, but getting FileNotFoundException after running the code. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Is it not taking the path of the XML file?

```
package com.javatpoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Test {  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("xmlContext.xml");
    //Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("xmlContext.xml");  
    //BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(resource);  

    Student student = (Student)context.getBean("studentbean");  
    student.displayName();  
  }
}
```

2)

```
package com.javatpoint;

public class Student {
  private String name;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void displayName() {
    System.out.println("Name :"+name);
  }
}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  

<bean id="studentbean" class="com.javatpoint.Student">  
  <property name="name" value="Vimal Jaiswal"></property>  
</bean>  

</beans>
```

Comment: Where have you defined xmlContext.xml? Is that location in classpath?

Comment: I think xmlContext.xml is not in your classpath location? You can add either the relative path or absolute path to get this fixed.

Comment: xmlConext.xml is present in the same com.javatpoint package